# Why is here a number?

Tags: bar-chart, chart.js

I am doing a bar chart and I have a problem with names of columns. I was trying also to give names of x and yAxes but here was a problem too. 
That's my dates from database:

```
[{ "id": "1", "paliwo": "200", "przebieg": "150", "jedzenie": "0" }]
```

[image]

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var paliwo = [];
            var przebieg = [];
            for (var i in data) {
                paliwo.push(data[i].paliwo);
                przebieg.push(data[i].przebieg);
            }
            var chartdata = {
                labels: paliwo,
                przebieg,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Paliwo',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: paliwo
                }, {
                    label: 'Przebieg',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: przebieg
                }]
            };
            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");
            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata,
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what's the relation to php?

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have given `labels:paliwo`; Labels denotes the x axis and `paliwo` contains [200]